# Insert multiple related tables in Entity at once

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables that are connected by foreign keys. I am trying to insert 1 row in the question table and two rows in the other two tables. I am getting the error 'Insert statement conflict with Foreign Key constraint'
Thank you in advance for the help

```
public void setMultiAnswer()
{
try
{
    string question = "Question 1"
    responsesList.Add("Answer1");
    responsesList.Add("Answer2");
    questionResponsesList.Add(false);
    questionResponsesList.Add(true);

    using (Entities testEntity = new Entities())
    {
        Question questionObj = new Question();
        questionObj.Question1 = question;
        questionObj.CreatedBy = "test";
        questionObj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        QuestionRespons questionResponsesObj = new QuestionRespons();
        // fill response
        foreach (var questionResponse in questionResponsesList)
        {
            questionResponsesObj.CorrectResponse = questionResponse;
        }

        questionObj.QuestionResponses.Add(questionResponsesObj);

        Response responseObj = new Response();

        // fill response 
        foreach (var response in responsesList)
        {
             responseObj.Response1 = response;
             responseObj.CreatedBy = "test";
             responseObj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        questionResponsesObj.Response = responseObj;

        testEntity.Questions.Add(questionObj);
        testEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex);
}
```

Comment: can you show the models code ?

Comment: Thank you I added the part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question id is autogenerated. In this case 
`int questionId = questionObj.QuestionID;`
will only work after the `SaveChanges()` call.

In general if you have an EntitySet with foreign keys it is easier to use the navigation properties instead of building id references yourself.

```
Question questionObj = new Question();
questionObj.CreatedBy = "Test";
questionObj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

QuestionRespons questionResponsesObj = new QuestionRespons();
// fill question response here
questionObj.QuestionResponses.Add(questionResponseObj);

Response responseObj = new Response();
// fill your response here
questionResponsesObj.Response = reponseObj;
// if you do the above in your loop you should be fine

testEntity.Questions.Add(questionObj);
testEntity.SaveChanges();
```

To match your example:

```
public void setMultiAnswer()
{
    try
    {
        string question = "Question 1"
        responsesList.Add("Answer1");
        responsesList.Add("Answer2");
        questionResponsesList.Add(false);
        questionResponsesList.Add(true);

        using (Entities testEntity = new Entities())
        {
            Question questionObj = new Question();
            questionObj.Question1 = question;
            questionObj.CreatedBy = "Test";
            questionObj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            testEntity.Questions.Add(questionObj);

            for (int i = 0; i < responsesList.Count; i++)
            {
                // i am not sure about your relation here, but i assume you require one QuestionResponse per response
                // which is why a moved the line of code
                QuestionRespons questionResponsesObj = new QuestionRespons();
                questionObj.QuestionResponses.Add(questionResponsesObj);

                Response responseObj = new Response();
                responseObj.Response1 = responsesList.ElementAt(i);
                responseObj.CreatedBy = "Test";
                responseObj.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseObj.Response1))
                {
                    questionResponsesObj.Response = responseObj;
                    questionResponsesObj.CorrectResponse = questionResponsesList.ElementAt(i);
                }

            }
            testEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to insert in table  Response as well. And the table questionResonses has foreign keys from the other two tables

Comment: I updated the excample to inculde Response, i'm not sure about your relation between `QuestionResponses` and `Reponse` which is why i did not include your for loop in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of

```
int questionId = questionObj.QuestionID;
testEntity.SaveChanges();
```

into

```
testEntity.SaveChanges();
int questionId = questionObj.QuestionID;
```

You created a new instance `questionObj` which should have a default ID of 0.
Only AFTER calling `SaveChanges()` the ID should be assigned the newly assigned actual ID value.

So, what happens here, is that you memorize `questionId` with the default value of `0` instead of the real ID. As a conseqence, the relations between questions and responses will always be wrong.

Comment: This splits an atomic process into two transactions -- not good.

Comment: @GertArnold Agreed! I would not implemet it that way, either. I just wanted to keep the answer short and without completely rewriting the full code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would remove this QuestionResponse table, to keep only Question and Response. Use the navigation properties instead of directly setting the foreign key.

```
    Question questionObj = new Question
    {
        Text = question,
        CreatedBy = "Test",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    foreach(var response in responsesList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
    {
        Response responseObj = new Response
        {
            Text = response,
            IsCorrect = true,
            CreatedBy = "Test",
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
        }

        questionObj.Add(responseObj);
    }

    testEntity.Questions.Add(questionObj);
    testEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How can I include the question response as well

Comment: No, the `QuestionResponse` entity can't be removed from the model, but setting navigation properties instead of FK values is entirely correct!

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion(you can see the code above). But I am entering only one questionResponse and response instead of two.

Comment: I suggested to remove the QuestionResponse table making the assumption the relation Response <-> Question should be one-to-many as it is unlikely to have same response related to many questions. If this is not pertinent please ignore the suggestion.